# Querying a Measure of a cube in .net using entityframeworkprovider

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ssas

I am Using EntityFrameworkProvider in .net to query the ssas cube called “NorthwindEF”

I have a Measure in a ssas cube called "ProductCount".

When I run this MDX query SQL Server :

```
SELECT {[Measures].ProductCount]} ON COLUMNS FROM [NorthwindEF]
```

The output is : 123

I have created a custom class as follows

```
[MeasureGroup]

Public partial class Product

{

  Public int ProductCount { get ; set; }
}
```

Similarly I want to retrieve this in .net using .

```
static void Main()

{

  var context = NorthwindEFEntities.CreateForOlap();

  var result = context. ProductCount.Select(o => o.Quantity);

}
```

But when I execute the following query I am getting the error as:

> {"Query (2, 1) The '[Product Count]' member  was not found in the
>   cube when the string, [Measures].[ Product Count], was parsed."} The
>   querybuilder is automatically assuming **ProductCount** as Product
>   Count ,which is generating the error.

Is there any way to avoid this?

This is the link which I followed:

http://www.agiledesignllc.com/GettingStartedGuide

Comment: should  var result = context. ProductCount.Select(o => o.Quantity); be  var result = context.Product.Select(o => o.Quantity);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

Mdx.NamingConvention = new PreserveSpecifiedNameConvention();

in the class where you create the custom class similar to generated entity classes from EF.
Thats it.